# Changing value in DataFrame based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If condition in column 1
And
If condition in column 2 are met 
Then 
change the value in column 1
This logic seems to work and returns True or False for each row in the df

```
data.id.isin([10,20,30,40]) & (data.source.isnull()
```

What I would like to do now is change the value of data.id to 50

I'm not getting an error with this logic but the value isn't changing

```
data.loc[(data.id.isin([10,20,30,40])) & (data.source.isnull()), 'id'] = 50
```

Comment: can you reproduce this in a sample df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used your code in this contained example the value seems to change correctly

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create example dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0,100,10), columns=['id'])
data.loc[3, 'source'] = 'foo'

# Change value
data.loc[(data.id.isin([10,20,30,40])) & (data.source.isnull()), 'id'] = 50
```

After that the id column has values [ 0, 50, 50, 30, 50, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]

Comment: I'm not sure what happened. I was working in Jupyter Notebook. I closed out and tried again and it works. Thanks for the help!